# Add a layout dynamically, to overlapp the other layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm writing a "Welcome Screen" for my application, that runs when application launches for the first time.
**What I want:** A transparent layout to be overlapped on the root layout, dynamically through code. like this image:

[image]

but when I run my app, It crashes due to NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION. even when I didn't add the second layout

**Problem 1:** Why first layout doesn't show up, and app crashes?

**Problem 2:** How to show the second layout?

thanks in advance....

**Authentication.java**

```
import component.Util;

public class Authentication extends Activity {

      private RelativeLayout rootLayout;
      public static Context CONTEXT;
      public Authentication(){
            CONTEXT=this;
    }

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    rootLayout=new RelativeLayout(CONTEXT);
    LinearLayout firstLayout=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.layout.authentication);

    rootLayout.addView(firstLayout);
    setContentView(rootLayout);

    if(Util.isFirstLaunch(CONTEXT)){
        //Add the second layout
    }
  }
}
```

**authentication.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/authentication"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/background" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView_login"
    android:layout_width="210dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="@string/loginText"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText_username"
    android:layout_width="210dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:nextFocusDown="@+id/editText_password"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:hint="@string/username" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText_password"
    android:layout_width="210dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:hint="@string/password" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_submit"
    android:layout_width="140dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/button"
    android:text="@string/submit"
    android:textColor="#e1ecff" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**stack trace:**

```
08-31 13:50:32.623: D/AndroidRuntime(5740): Shutting down VM
08-31 13:50:32.623: W/dalvikvm(5740): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
08-31 13:50:32.643: E/AndroidRuntime(5740): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-31 13:50:32.643: E/AndroidRuntime(5740): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.shayan.filesharing/com.shayan.filesharing.Authentication}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.RelativeLayout
08-31 13:50:32.643: E/AndroidRuntime(5740):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
08-31 13:50:32.643: E/AndroidRuntime(5740):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
08-31 13:50:32.643: E/AndroidRuntime(5740):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
08-31 13:50:32.643: E/AndroidRuntime(5740):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
08-31 13:50:32.643: E/AndroidRuntime(5740):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-31 13:50:32.643: E/AndroidRuntime(5740):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-31 13:50:32.643: E/AndroidRuntime(5740):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
08-31 13:50:32.643: E/AndroidRuntime(5740):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-31 13:50:32.643: E/AndroidRuntime(5740):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-31 13:50:32.643: E/AndroidRuntime(5740):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
08-31 13:50:32.643: E/AndroidRuntime(5740):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
08-31 13:50:32.643: E/AndroidRuntime(5740):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-31 13:50:32.643: E/AndroidRuntime(5740): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.RelativeLayout
08-31 13:50:32.643: E/AndroidRuntime(5740):     at com.shayan.filesharing.Authentication.onCreate(Authentication.java:22)
08-31 13:50:32.643: E/AndroidRuntime(5740):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
08-31 13:50:32.643: E/AndroidRuntime(5740):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
08-31 13:50:32.643: E/AndroidRuntime(5740):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
08-31 13:50:32.643: E/AndroidRuntime(5740):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: The `Context` is valid only starting with the `onCreate` method so please don't do `CONTEXT=this;` in the constructor of the `Activity`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, delete your constructor. Do not implement a constructor on an `Activity`. You do not need one, and you implemented it incorrectly (failed to chain to the superclass).

Second, delete your `CONTEXT` static data member. Do not put an `Activity` in a static data member, as you will leak memory. Replace all references to `CONTEXT` with `this` in your `onCreate()` method.

Comment: I need CONTEXT for instantiating one of my classes, inside the onClickListener, where "this" refers to View.onClickListener, not the Activity's context. what should I do instead?

Comment: @Shayan_Aryan: "what should I do instead?" -- use `Authentication.this`, not `CONTEXT`.

Comment: thanks for the info, I did what you said. but app still crashes!!

Comment: @Shayan_Aryan: Then edit your question and post the stack trace.

Comment: I've founded out that error comes from this line :   rootLayout.addView(firstLayout);

Comment: @Shayan_Aryan: Use the `addView()` that takes a `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` second parameter, so that you can indicate where inside the `RelativeLayout` this `LinearLayout` should go. If all you want is something else to be stacked on top of your `LinearLayout`, I'd use `FrameLayout` rather than `RelativeLayout`, as it supports stacking and is a bit simpler to use.

Answer (score 0):

corrected 2 things, and the problem solved.

**1 :**  used the LayoutParams inside addView(), and the FrameLayout instead of RelativeLayout

**2 :**  used getLayoutInflater.inflate() instead of findViewByID(). because we can't call findViewByID() when the root layout is not displayed yet (not inflated).

**Authentication.java:**

```
import component.Util;

public class Authentication extends Activity {
   private FrameLayout rootLayout;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    rootLayout=new FrameLayout(this);
    LinearLayout authenticationView=(LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.authentication, rootLayout, false);
    rootLayout.addView(authenticationView,FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    setContentView(rootLayout);
    if(Util.isFirstLaunch(this)){
        ImageView image=(ImageView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.first_run_info,rootLayout,false);
        rootLayout.addView(image,FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    }
  }
}
```